# Proving a limit involving Big-O-Notation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Let $x\in \mathbb{R^3},x\neq 0$ and $w_0\in \mathbb{C}$. How do I show that the limit

$$\lim_{w\to w_0} \frac{x\cdot \lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m}+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m+1})}{\lvert x\cdot \lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m}+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m+1})\rvert} $$
exists and is equal to $\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}$? I am having trouble with the $O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert ^{2m+1})$ terms.

Comment: Divide top & bottom by $|w-w_0|^{2m}$, then factor out $x$ & $|x|$.

Comment: Rename $w-w_0=d$, then $d \to0$, will probably look a bit easier for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $\lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m}$ we have that

$$ \frac{x\cdot \lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m}+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m+1})}{\lvert x\cdot \lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m}+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert^{2m+1})\rvert}= \frac{x+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert)}{\lvert x+O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert)\rvert}\to\frac x{|x|}$$

since by definition

$$\lim_{w\to w_0} O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert)=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I was too focussed on dividing by $O(\lvert w-w_0\rvert)^{2m+1})$ that I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the limit as $w \to w_0$, so $w-w_0$ is small.  Raising a small number to a large power makes it smaller yet, so $(w-w_0)^{2m+1}$ becomes negligible compared to $(w-w_0)^{2m}$